# java performance on two different servers

Tags: java, performance, settings, cpu

not sure if this question should be here or in serverfault, but it's java-related so here it is:

I have two servers, with very similar technology:

- server1 is Oracle/Sun x86 with dual x5670 CPU (2.93 GHz) (4 cores each), 12GB RAM.
- server2 is Dell R610 with dual x5680 CPU (3.3 GHz) (6 cores each), 16GB RAM.

both are running Solaris x86, with exact same configuration.

both have turbo-boost enabled, and no hyper-threading.

server2 should therefore be SLIGHTLY faster than server1.

I'm running the following short test program on the two platforms.

```
import java.io.*;

public class TestProgram {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new TestProgram ();
}

public TestProgram () {
    try {
        PrintWriter writer  = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("perfs.txt", true), true);

        for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
            long t1 = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println("0123456789qwertyuiop0123456789qwertyuiop0123456789qwertyuiop0123456789qwertyuiop");
            long t2 = System.nanoTime();

            writer.println((t2-t1));

            //try {
            //  Thread.sleep(1);
            //}
            //catch(Exception e) {
            //  System.out.println("thread sleep exception");
            //}
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);
    }
}
}
```

I'm opening perfs.txt and averaging the results, I get:

- server1: average = 1664 , trim 10% = 1615
- server2: average = 1510 , trim 10% = 1429

which is a somewhat expected result (server2 perfs > server1 perfs).

now, I uncomment the "Thread.sleep(1)" part and test again, the results are now:

- server1: average = 27598 , trim 10% = 26583
- server2: average = 52320 , trim 10% = 39359

this time server2 perfs < server1 perfs

that doesn't make any sense to me...

obviously I'm looking at a way to improve server2 perfs in the second case. there must be some kind of configuration that is different, and I don't know which one.
OS are identical, java version are identical.

could it be linked to the number of cores ?
maybe it's a BIOS setting ? although BIOS are different (AMI vs Dell), settings seem pretty similar.

I'll update the Dell's BIOS soon and retest, but I would appreciate any insight...

thanks

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but given the code you posted, it doesn't make any sense that uncommenting the Thread.sleep() call even affects the times at all. It would only make sense if you took the t2 time *after* the Thread.sleep().

Comment: May be Disk cache difference?

Comment: @davmac : you're not misunderstanding, and you're right, it doesn't make any sense, but still, it's the results I get, and that's why I'm posting.

Comment: @isobar : I can check that, however I forgot to mention that although I'm using "System.out.println", the same result pattern is obtained when doing any kind of computation, even not including I/O (I tried with a long serie of Math computation, same pattern)

Comment: What are you really trying to measure? Your program is not even close to a valid comparison of server performance - System.out.println is not exactly a benchmark yardstick. Why don't you use one of the out-of-the-box benchmarks? I like VolanoMark (http://www.volano.com/benchmarks.html) because it is no-nonsense to set up, and gives (IME) a very legitimate comparison of server "beef" for typical web applications.

Comment: @jkraybill : performance measurement is not the final goal. I have a much bigger program that I'm running in production on server1. we purchased server2 to move away from Sun servers, and also to improve perfs (faster CPU). but when testing the program, it was running much slower on the DELL. I managed to strip down the program and isolate the "slow" part on the Dell vs the Sun, and that's this part. I'm trying to understand how to make the Dell as fast as the Sun. Also note that it's not a web application. It's a trading engine for which single-thread perf / latency is the most important.

Comment: @Bastien - that may all be true, but unless your program is doing many, many System.out.println statements as part of its normal operation, your program won't demonstrate anything useful. Are you also are aware that System.nanoTime, especially used across such a small window, is likely not accurate when comparing results from 2 different hardware configs?

Comment: @jkraybill : also, System.out.println is what is used in my big program, that's why I'm comparing its performances. however, as mentionned above, the SAME result pattern is observed when using a different kind of computation (Math library for example).

Comment: @jkraybill : and for nanotime, it's accurate enough for our "big" program, so I've slowly stripped down the big program and reached this small test program. I agree that when getting around 1500ns, it starts to be meaningless (the "cost" of calling nanotime seems to be around 300ns on my systems), however, for the computation including the sleep method, that averages at 30,000ns, it's precise enough. keep in mind that I'm not comparing single nanotime values, but differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually updated the BIOS on the DELL R610 and ensured all BIOS CPU parameters are adjusted for best low-latency performances (no hyper-threading, etc...).
it solved it. The performances with & without the Thread.sleep make sense, and the overall performances of the R610 in both cases are much better than the Sun.
It appears the original BIOS did not make a correct or a full usage of the nehalem capabilities (while the Sun did).

Answer (score 0):

I would try a different test program, try running somthing like this.

```
public class Timer implements Runnable
{
    public void startTimer()
    {
        time = 0;
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();
    }

    public int stopTimer()
    {
        running = false;
        return time;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            while(running)
            { 
                Thread.sleep(1);
                time++;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    private int time;
    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running;
}
```

Thats the timer now heres the main:

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        timer.startTimer();
        for(int x=0;x<1000;x++)
            System.out.println("Testing!!");
        System.out.println("\n\nTime Taken: "+timer.stopTimer());
     }
}
```

I think this is a good way to test wich system is truely running faster. Try this and let me know how it goes.

Comment: this test does not replicate the production program that I'm trying to improve, but I still ran it, and got "expected" results: server2 is faster than server1. I still can't explain why my program runs slower on serve2.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have a theory: the Thread.sleep() prevents the hotspot compiler from kicking in. Because you have a sleep, it assumes the loop isn't "hot", i.e that it doesn't matter too much how efficient the code in the loop is (because, after all, you're sleep's only purpose could be to slow things down).

Hence, you add a Thread.sleep() inside the loop, and the other stuff in the loop also runs slower.

I wonder if it might make a difference if you have a loop inside a loop and measure the performance of the inner loop? (and only have the Thread.sleep() in the outer loop). In this case the compiler might optimize the inner loop (if there are enough iterations).

(Brings up a question: if this code is a test case extracted from production code, why does the production code sleep?)

Comment: interesting. however, why would the compiler behave differently on two systems that are running same OS version and same java version ? behavior should be identical, no ? the VM / compiler doesn't interact with the HW itself, but with the OS, right ? and even in this case, HW is still "faster" on server2. The code is not EXACTLY the same in production, there are basically concurrent threads. I started with testing it this way by running other threads next to it, and slowly continued to isolate the issue, and reached that point.

Answer (score -1):

You are testing how fast the console updates.  This is entirely OS and window dependent. If you run this in your IDE it will be much slower than running in an xterm.  Even which font you use and how big your window is will make a big different to performance. If your window is closed while you run the test this will improve performance.

---

Here is how I would run the same test.  This test is self contained and does the analysis you need.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TestProgram {
    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("out.txt");
        file.deleteOnExit();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file), true);

        int runs = 100000;
        long[] times = new long[runs];
        for (int i = -10000; i < runs; i++) {
            long t1 = System.nanoTime();
            out.println("0123456789qwertyuiop0123456789qwertyuiop0123456789qwertyuiop0123456789qwertyuiop");
            long t2 = System.nanoTime();
            if (i >= 0)
                times[i] = t2 - t1;
        }
        out.close();
        Arrays.sort(times);
        System.out.printf("Median time was %,d ns, the 90%%tile was %,d ns%n", times[times.length / 2], times[times.length * 9 / 10]);
    }
}
```

prints on a 2.6 GHz Xeon WIndows Vista box

```
Median time was 3,213 ns, the 90%tile was 3,981 ns
```

Comment: no, actually I'm redirecting standard output to file, so there's none of this involved. additionally, as mentionned above, the result pattern is the same if System.out.println is replaced by non-IO code, such as several Math computations.

Comment: your test is indeed good, and the results I get are the ones expected: 2000 ns on 2.93GHz, 1860 ns on 3.3GHz. HOWEVER, my problem is to understand WHY I don't get the same pattern in my original test case with the "Thread.sleep()" line (which corresponds to production), and this is my original issue. the only difference being the number of cores (2*4 vs 2*6)...